# Mongo `pre` hook not firing as expected on `save()` operation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using `pre` and `post` hooks in my MongoDB/Node backend in order to compare a pre-save and post-save version of a document so I can generate notes via model triggers based on what's changed. In one of my models/collections this is working, but in another, it's not working as expected, and I'm not sure why.

In the problem case, some research has determined that even though I am calling a `pre` hook trigger on an operation that uses a `save()`, when I console out the doc state passed in that `pre` hook, it's already had the change applied. In other words, the hook is not firing before the `save()` operation, but after, from what I can tell.

Here is my relevant model code:

```
let Schema = mongoose
  .Schema(CustomerSchema, {
    timestamps: true
  })
  .pre("save", function(next) {
    const doc = this;
    console.log("doc in .pre: ", doc); // this should be the pre-save version of the doc, but it is the post-save version
    console.log("doc.history.length in model doc: ", doc.history.length);
    trigger.preSave(doc);
    next();
  })
  .post("save", function(doc) {
    trigger.postSave(doc);
  })
  .post("update", function(doc) {
    trigger.postSave(doc);
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Customer", Schema);
```

The relevant part of the `save()` operation that I'm doing looks like this (all I'm doing is pushing a new element to an array on the doc called "history"):

```
exports.updateHistory = async function(req, res) {
  let request = new CentralReqController(
    req,
    res,
    {
      // Allowed Parameters
      id: {
        type: String
      },
      stageId: {
        type: String
      },
      startedBy: {
        type: String
      }
    },
    [
      // Required Parameters
      "id",
      "stageId",
      "startedBy"
    ]
  );

  let newHistoryObj = {
    stageId: request.parameters.stageId,
    startDate: new Date(),
    startedBy: request.parameters.startedBy,
    completed: false
  };

  let customerToUpdate = await Customer.findOne({
    _id: request.parameters.id
  }).exec();

  let historyArray = await customerToUpdate.history;

  console.log("historyArray.length before push in update func: ", historyArray.length);

  historyArray.push(newHistoryObj);

  await customerToUpdate.save((err, doc) => {
    if (doc) console.log("history update saved...");
    if (err) return request.sendError("Customer history update failed.", err);
  });
};
```

So, my question is, if a `pre` hook on a `save()` operation is supposed to fire BEFORE the `save()` happens, why does the document I look at via my console.log show a document that's already had the `save()` operation done on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a bit mistaken on what the pre/post 'save' hooks are doing. In pre/post hook terms, `save` is the actual save operation to the database. That being said, the `this` you have in the `pre('save')` hook, is the object you called `.save()` on, not the updated object from the database. For example:

```
let myCustomer = req.body.customer; // some customer object

// Update the customer object
myCustomer.name = 'Updated Name';

// Save the customer
myCustomer.save();
```

We just updated the customers name. When the `.save()` is called, it triggers the hooks, like you stated above. Only the difference is, the `this` in the `pre('save')` hook is the **same object as myCustomer**, not the updated object from the database. On the contrary, the `doc` object in the `post('save') hook **IS** the updated object from the database.

```
Schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  console.log(this); // Modified object (myCustomer), not from DB
)};

Schema.post('save', function(doc) {
  console.log(doc); // Modified object DIRECTLY from DB
});
```

Comment: So, to clarify, you're saying the `pre` save hook doesn't actually read the document from the database at all? Are you sure about that? The reason why that seems off to me is that this same setup works for my other collection - and I don't see how it could if what you're saying is true.

Comment: That's exactly it!! Try it out, set a timeout on the `next()` function, and keep checking your database. Your `pre('save)'` will be called, and the object in the database wont be changed until `next()` is called

Comment: I added my full function code above. Please check and confirm this still looks like the issue to you.

Comment: Correct, `next()` determines when to go to the next function, so when you call `next()`, the next step is to upload to the database.

Comment: If you don't believe what I am saying, try changing a field in the `pre('save')`. Update the customer name or something. You will see it be changed in the database, since the actual database update happens after the `pre('save')`

Comment: In response to that, I don't know what you SHOULD be doing. That being said, what you are trying to accomplish should NOT be done in the hooks

Comment: Right, but this raises the question, what's the generally suggested Mongo approach when you need to compare documents in their pre and post-save versions in order to handle creating system notes and the like. I thought this is what the hooks were intended for. 

Also, as I mentioned, this doesn't explain how virtually the same code works as expected in my other collection. That confuses me if this is true. By the way, do you happen to have the reference to this in the docs?

Comment: Try using .`updateOne()` instead. This makes a call to the database to update the object, without you actually changing the object. You can then do a findOne() and retrieve the updated object from the database. Now your `updateHistory()` function, you should have the old version, and the new version. It's messy, but I dont know of a better way.

Comment: Right, that could work. Marking this answer as correct. Thanks!